# Can the fpos_t type take a null value?

Tags: c

I know that pointers can be set to null (e.g. to indicate that the object being pointed to does not exist), and no valid pointer will point to null; can the same be done with the `fpos_t` type, such that no valid position will be null?

Comment: We don't know -- `fpos_t` is an opaque type. It may or may not have such a value.

Comment: <s>Please change the tag to C++ if this is (as I suspect) a C++ question not a C question. Alternatively, please specify which C library it refers too. An answer below has since made me doubt myself, but I thought POSIX C libraries have `fgetpos` etc use `long` not `fpos_t`.</s> - see my answer below.

Comment: @H2CO3 indeed the standard says it contains *unspecified information*.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know as H2CO3 said, it is an opaque type. More formerly it is *unspecified*, this is what the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says, in section `7.19.1`:

> fpos_t
>
> which is an object type other than an array type capable of recording all the information
>   needed to specify uniquely every position within a file.

and in section `7.19.9.1` *The fgetpos function* says (*emphasis mine*):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fgetpos(FILE * restrict stream, fpos_t * restrict pos);
```

> The fgetpos function stores the current values of the parse state (if any) and file
>   position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream in the object pointed to by pos.
>   **The values stored contain unspecified information usable by the fsetpos function** for
>   repositioning the stream to its position at the time of the call to the fgetpos function.

Answer (score 0):

`fpos_t` is typically an unsigned integer type. On most systems `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int` or `unsigned long long int`. Othen has the same type as `size_t`. As such interpretation of a "valid" offset depends on the function that consumes it. System calls will typically fail with `EINVAL` if an invalid offset is supplied.

Invalid offset is often referred to as "offset too large". Some system calls may also require offsets to be aligned to for example page boundaries.

If you wish to have an "invalid" offset I suggest you try setting it to the largest possible i.e. `(fpos_t)-1`. There is no universal way though.

Comment: Is that C `fpos_t` a standard thing or part (e.g.) MS API? POSIX `ftell` etc. return `long` not `fpos_t`. The only `fpos_t` I know of is C++.

Comment: @abligh `fpos_t` is in my `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 0):

<s>This is a C++ question not a C question, as `fpos_t` is not part of the C standard to my knowledge.</s>

In C++, `fpos_t` is defined as 'A non-array type containing all information needed to specify uniquely every position within a file'. See:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdio.h.html#tag_13_49

I believe it is normally a struct, though theoretically it could be a pointer. However, it's implementation defined. As such it can't (reliably and portably) be a `NULL` and normally this will fail.

In C (you learn a new thing every day), it's still an opaque type. See e.g.:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Portable-Positioning.html

*In the GNU C Library, fpos_t is an opaque data structure that contains internal data to represent file offset and conversion state information. In other systems, it might have a different internal representation.*

Comment: I see `fpos_t` in the C99 draft, first mention section `7.19.1`.

Comment: You are quite right. I fixed my answer, but I think you deserve the credit for this one. The gnu libc manpages specify `long`. Clearly I should have gone to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

The content of an fpos_t object is not meant to be read directly, but only to be used as an argument in a call to fsetpos.